# Javascript Redux update nested object property value

Tags: javascript, redux, nested, store, updating

I have a question. How can I update my value in my nested object ?

so my Redux state looks like:

```
const initialState = {
    elements: [],
    selectedElement: {},

};
```

In elements array I will storage my "elements" with structure like this:

```
   {
        id: 3243,
        elemType: 'p',
        content: 'some example content',
        style: {
            fontSize: 30,
            color: "red",
            textDecoration: "underline",
            fontFamily: "Arial"
        }
    }
```

And now I'd like change values in style. Maybe fontSize, maybe color... depends which property will be selected.

I've made action creator which give me id, property, value for these changes.. but the problem is that I don't know how to exactly write code in reducer :(

**Action Creator**

```
   export const updateElement = (property, value, id) => {
    return {
        type: 'UPDATE_ELEMENT',
        property,
        value,
        id
    }
}
```

**Reducer**

```
const {id, elemType, content, style, type, selected, property, value} = action;

        case 'UPDATE_ELEMENT':
                const elementForUpdate = state.elements.find(element => element.id === id);
                console.log(id, property, value);
                return ...?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you have to maintain [immutability](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns). In your case, you have to make sure that:

1. The `elements` array is copied.
2. The updated element object is copied.
3. The `style` object of the updated element is copied.

You can accomplish all of these with a single `map`:

```
case 'UPDATE_ELEMENT': {
    const elements = state.elements.map(el => {
        if (el.id === id) {
            const style = { ...el.style, [property]: value };
            return { ...el, style };
        } else {
            return el;
        }
    });

    return { ...state, elements };
}
```

Comment: Amazing. This is exactly what I looked for :) Thank you :) and thank you for advice ;)